# tvOS how to recognize remote gestures for Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

How would I go about recognizing remote swipes and button taps with Objective C for tvOS? Everywhere I find comes up with Swift, which I'm not used to yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a link to one of the examples of doing it in Swift?

Comment: http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.com/2015/09/quick-tip-how-to-use-remote-control-in.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Swift code from your example:

```
let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
swipeDown.direction = .Down
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    NSLog("It worked")
}
```

Swift 5:

```
let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
swipeDown.direction = .down
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    NSLog("It worked")
}
```

Translating to Objective C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"It works");
}
```

Which seems to work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example of swift code.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped")
tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer:  UIPressType.Select.rawValue)];
self.tabBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

let swipeRecognizerRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipedRight")
swipeRecognizerRight.direction = .Right //.Left,.Up,.Down.
self.tabBar.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```

And these Method:

```
func tapped(){

    // write her your code.

}

func swipeRecognizer(){

   // write her your code.

}
```